# addEventListener for 'push' in vue-cli with service worker

Tags: vue.js, service, command-line-interface, progressive-web-apps, worker

I am using a *NodeJs backend server*, and for my frontend web application, I am using Vue-CLI. Backend sits on one port for the `localhost` and the frontend app on another port in development mode.

I am attempting to implement push notifications by using web-push npm and the service worker that comes with Vue CLI. However, I do not know where I should put the `eventListener` for `'push'`.

I tried creating a file called `service-worker.js` in the (frontend/) main dir (where the `registerServiceWorker.js` is). In the following code, I just threw the `eventListener` in the `registerServiceWorker.js` file.

Thanks in advance!

Frontend(registerServiceWorker.js):

```js
/* eslint-disable no-console */
console.log('baseURL:', process.env.BASE_URL)
const BACKEND_SUBSCRIBE = (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development')
    ? '/subscribe'
    : '//localhost:3003/subscribe';

import { register } from 'register-service-worker'
import {convertedVapidKey} from './services/PushNotificationService'
import Axios from 'axios';
const axios = Axios.create({
  withCredentials: true
});

self.addEventListener('push', function(e) {
  console.log('Hi');
  const data = e.data.json();
  self.registration.showNotification(data.title, {
    body: 'Notified by me',
    icon: 'icon'
  });
});

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  register(`${process.env.BASE_URL}service-worker.js`, {
    ready (sw) {
      sw.pushManager.subscribe({
        userVisibleOnly: true,
        applicationServerKey: convertedVapidKey
      }).then(sub => {
        console.log('sending sub', sub)
        axios.post(BACKEND_SUBSCRIBE, sub)
        .then(res => {
           console.log('sent sub,', res)
        });
      })
    },
```

backend(server.js):

```js
const webpush = require('web-push');

const publicKey= 'keystring';
const privateKey = 'keystring'
webpush.setVapidDetails(
    'mailto:my@app.com',
    publicKey,
    privateKey
)

app.post('/subscribe', (req, res) => {
        const subscription = req.body;
        console.log(subscription);
        // send 201 status
        res.status(201).json({'see':'see this?'});

        // create payload
        const payload = JSON.stringify({ title: 'Push test'});

        webpush.sendNotification(subscription, payload)
        .catch(err => console.log(err));

})
```

Comment: Could you tell us what is your issue here? Have you encountered an error when calling the `push eventListener`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My problem was that I tried to run this in development mode (I also was naive to set the 'registerServiceWorker.js' to act as if in dev mode. What I had to do was just build my vue-cli project, go to the backend/public file and paste the event listener there in the service-worker.js file. I managed to receive push notifications. However, it does not work on mobile phones, which is a bummer.

Answer (score 4):

After all the headache what I had to do was to configure a "vue.config.js" file in the main frontend like this:

```js
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
    pwa: {
      workboxPluginMode: 'InjectManifest',
      workboxOptions: {
          swSrc: 'src/service-worker.js'
      },
      themeColor: '#8bc34a'
    },
  }
```

That allowed me to paste my push event listeners inside the src/service-worker.js file :)